# How can add an another input from classes

Tags: c#, console

Hello I have a little problem. I make some classes and inheritance them and now I need to know how to add another value in the same method. Need to have 2 different value :

```
          ` hastane Hbenim = new hastane();
            Hbenim.ID = 1234;
            Hbenim.SpitalNAme = "AmericA HosPital";
            Hbenim.SpitalAdres = "Tirana Albania";
            Hbenim.workersNumber = 100;

            Hbenim.PersonelAdi = "Amir";
            Hbenim.PersonelAdres = "KAraj";
            Hbenim.PersonelTCno = 9928931;
            Hbenim.PersonelAdres = "Elbasan Arnavutluk";
            Hbenim.ServisIdNum = 34;
            Hbenim.ServisName = "Albatur Expres";
            Hbenim.ServicePlace = "Elbasan";

            Console.WriteLine("Hospital Id Number: " + Hbenim.ID);
            Console.WriteLine("Hospital Name: " + Hbenim.SpitalNAme);
            Console.WriteLine("Hospital Adres: " + Hbenim.SpitalAdres);
            Console.WriteLine("\nHosppital Workers Number: " + Hbenim.workersNumber);

            Console.WriteLine("Hospital Personel1 Name: " + Hbenim.PersonelAdi);
            Console.WriteLine("Hospital Personel2 Name: " + Hbenim.PersonelAdi);
            Console.WriteLine("Hospital Servise No: " + Hbenim.ServisIdNum);
            Console.WriteLine("Hospital Services Name: " + Hbenim.ServisName);
            Console.WriteLine("Hospital Services Place: " + Hbenim.ServicePlace);


            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}`
```

How to add another personnel value in Hbenim methods. Thank you

Comment: Add another property to your `hastane` class... and I suggest doing some research into naming conventions

Comment: those class and property names dont tell me anything so i cant help you. why would you write half english and half another language? if its english then stay on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a nested collection for the personnel information such as:

```
public class Hbenim{
   string blah
   string blah
   IList<Personnel> Personnel 
}

public class Personnel{
  string blah
  string blah
}
```